# How to group this arrays by id?

Tags: reactjs

Sort this array of objects
    [
      {
        color: "#000000",
        id: 1,
        image: "",
        languageId: 1,
        name: "Black",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 1
      },
      {
        color: "#000000",
        id: 1,
        image: "",
        languageId: 2,
        name: "สีดำ"
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 1,
      },
      {
        color: "#ffffff",
        id: 2,
        image: "",
        languageId: 1,
        name: "White",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 2
      },
      {
        color: "#ffffff",
        id: 2,
        image: "",
        languageId: 2,
        name: "ขาว",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 2
      },
      {
        color: "#c0c0c0",
        id: 3,
        image: "",
        languageId: 1,
        name: "Gray",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 3
       },
      {
        color: "#c0c0c0",
        id: 3,
        image: "",
        languageId: 2,
        name: "สีเทา",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 3
      },
      {
        color: "#b3b300",
        id: 4,
        image: "",
        languageId: 1,
        name: "Golden",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 4
      },
      {
        color: "#b3b300",
        id: 4,
        image: "",
        languageId: 2,
        name: "โกลเด้น",
        productAttributeId: 1,
        sortOrder: 4
      }
      ]

Comment: Those are not elements. *Those* is a string. Not even sure what's its format. Array of Objects?

Comment: is this an array of objects ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of objects, where each object has an id, then you can do the following:

```
array.sort((a - b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```js
data = [{
    color: "#000000",
    id: 1,
    image: "",
    languageId: 1,
    name: "Black",
    productAttributeId: 1,
    sortOrder: 1
},
{
    color: "#000000",
    id: 2,
    image: "",
    languageId: 1,
    name: "Blue",
    productAttributeId: 1,
    sortOrder: 1
},
{
    color: "#000000",
    id: 1,
    image: "",
    languageId: 1,
    name: "Green",
    productAttributeId: 1,
    sortOrder: 1
}
];


function groupByField(data, field){
    const groupedByObject = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        const rest = Object.keys(val).reduce((newObj, key) => {
            if(key !== field){
                newObj[key] = val[key]
            }
            return newObj;
        }, {});
        if (acc[val[field]]) {
          acc[val[field]].push(rest);
        } else {;
          acc[val[field]] = [rest];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})

    return Object.keys(groupedByObject).map(key => ({[field]: key, items: groupedByObject[key]}))

}

a = groupByField(data,"id");
console.log("Grouped by Id")
console.log(a);



b = groupByField(data, "languageId");
console.log("Grouped by languageId")
console.log(b);
```

try something like this.